# Building an array in for loop with asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to do something as below. I want to iterate over a list, and make database calls that are dependant upon the item in the list. Obviously, because the calls are async, by the time the for loop ends, no calls have returned, and therefore the list is empty.

In c#, I could await the database call and that would work fine. I've tried to find a similar approach in javascript, but I'm not having much luck

```
exports.methodName = (req, res) => {

    var itemsToReturn = []

    for (let item of list) {
        db.all(sql), (err, rows) => {
            itemsToReturn.push(rows)
        }
    }

    res.json(itemsToReturn )
}
```

I'm using SQLite as my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way to do this in Javascript would be to use or create a promise interface (instead of the callback interface you show) for `db.all()` and then use `Promise.all()` on an array of promises to know when all the async operations are done.  You don't say what your database is so we can't offer any help on whether your database already has a promise interface (many do now).

Here's the manual way of doing things assuming `list` is an array:

```
exports.methodName = (req, res) => {

    let itemsToReturn = [];
    let cntr = 0;
    for (let [index, item] of list.entries()) {
        db.all(sql), (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
               // insert error handling here
            } else {
                itemsToReturn[index] = rows;
                ++cntr;
                if (cntr === list.length) {
                    res.json(itemsToReturn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you had a promise interface to your database called `db.allPromise()`, you could do something like this:

```
exports.methodName = (req, res) => {

    Promise.all(list.map(item => {
        return db.all(someSql);
    })).then(results => {
        res.json(results);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks :) I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on

Comment: @Ralt - I added an example of how it would work with promises which is the more modern way of managing multiple async operations.

Comment: @Ralt - It looks like in some versions of SQLite, `db.all()` already returns a promise so you could use my second implementation.

Comment: It's better to move counter out of if/else

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani - That depends upon what your error handling is doing and how you want to handle errors. You did not specify what you wanted to do on errors so I did not fill in that branch of the `if`. You will find that proper error handling when handling multiple async operations manually (as in the first example above) is hard - whereas it is very simple with promises (my second example above.  If you want to continue processing on an error and still get to the `res.json()` output, then yes you would need to always increment the counter, but I doubt that's really what you want to do.

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani - If you want to immediately send an error when you get an error, then you would not want to increment the counter because you don't want the code to try to send `res.json()` when there was an error.